# extract text from dwg file

Tags: autocad, cad

Does anyone have an idea on how to extract the text in dwg file? I have 4000 tags and want to compare them with an Excel. Don't want to do it with my eyes.

I only have DWG trueview installed. But, if other software is needed, I can find them.

[image]

Comment: Hi, I think this question is not really about programming but about using software. FYI, you can do this with [autocad](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-50BEF344-C735-45C1-A0D1-D0F901BAEBB9-htm.html)

Comment: Jacques is correct, this is more of a functionality of software question, as TrueView does not have an API available last I was aware and a terse search seems to confirm that is still the case.  AutoCAD certainly has the needed tools within its API to give you what you're looking for, if you're not looking for a development option though, the AutoDesk forums may be a better option for you, or Superuser if you wish to stay within the SE Network.

Answer (score 0):

try this service https://dwg2docx.com

i think it's help to you